# MDC-Web: How to Setup MDC-Web Vanilla

Tags: material-design, material-components

I'm using a basic file manager to maintain my webpages files. How to I begin using [MDC-Web Vanilla](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/developer.md)?

In the [MDC-Web Github project folder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/material-components-web) are: README.md, index.js, material-components-web.scss, and package.json.

I would expect to find `<link>` and `<script>` elements to add to MDC-Web to my project, similar to how [MDL](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) work.  Where do I find those?

Comment: From what I see, the project uses ES6 modules, not yet support by all browser e.g. Chrome. webpack build the components into one bundle with the option of translation to support browser with no ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You need to [attach/initialize JS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/importing-js.md) on some components/elements.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code above threw an error for me. That error is fixed by replacing "MDCTextfield" with "MDCTextField". But after fixing that error, I get another: "material-components-web.min.js:262 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null". Would you check that your code sample above still runs please?

Comment: @MartinOmander Got it. MDC-Web has made a few updates that are not backward compatible (like 'mdc-simple-menu' is now 'mdc-menu').